# How do I make it so this message gets sent a specific channel? (Discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

I want the message to get sent to a specific channel

```
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    await before.channel.send(
        f'{before.author} edited a message.\n'
        f'Before: {before.content}\n'
        f'After: {after.content}'
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a message in a specific channel you need first to fetch the choosed channel by using his id by using `get_channel()` like this:

```py
specificChannel = bot.get_channel(int(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID_HERE))
```

Then your event block should look like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    specificChannel = bot.get_channel(int(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID_HERE))
    await specificChannel.send(
        f'{before.author} edited a message.\n'
        f'Before: {before.content}\n'
        f'After: {after.content}'
)
```

Useful link:

[get_channel()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel)

[Discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score -1):

maybe this can help u :)

```py
    @client.event
    async def on_member_join(member:Member):
        if member.bot:
            guild:discord.Guild = member.guild
            role = guild.get_role(config.botRoleID)
            channel:discord.TextChannel = guild.get_channel(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID)
            await member.add_roles(role)
            await channel.send(f'Set Bot role to "{member.display_name}" ')
```

Comment: It doesn't, sorry.

Comment: What is the console output?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).